# What function satisfies these conditions?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

In order to solve the PDE I am working with, I need to determine a function $u(x,t)$ that satisfies both of these conditions

$$u(0,t)=\sin(t)$$
$$u(1,t)=\cos(t)$$

I know it is just trial and error but I can't seem to think of a function that has this. Thanks guys

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$u(x,t)=x\cos(t)+(1-x)\sin(t)$$

Are there other conditions, too?

Comment: Is there anyway to determine this other than trial and error?

Comment: This is a pretty standard trick, actually. If you need a function in $x$ and $t$ to look like $f(t)$ when $x=0$ and $g(t)$ when $x=1$, then $$x g(t)+(1-x)f(t)$$ does the job. I'm blanking on the term for this trick at the moment, though.

Comment: Linear interpolation? You are just "drawing a straight line between the two points".

Comment: actually there was a third condition that i just saw and it was $u(x,0)=x$ so your function satisfies that as well. Thank you

Comment: I was able to do the rest of the problem. That was the first step of many. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @FixedPoint: Thank you! That's what I was looking for.

Comment: @Greg: Glad to help!

Comment: I just took a partial differential equations exam and I had to find a function $v(x,t)$ to satisfy these two boundary conditions:
$$u(0,t)=0$$
$$u(a,t)=0$$

and this initial condition: $u(x,0)=0$. I was stuck on this for most of the test and could not figure out $v(x,t)$ so I did the whole problem without it. What is it, it was driving me crazy

Comment: @GregHarrington Well, in this case $u(x,t)=0$ would work. Are you sure the initial condition was zero? Was there a PDE to solve or just find a function satisfying these conditions?

Comment: @Greg: Fixed Point has given the simplest example. Also, for any positive integer $k$ (assuming that $a\neq 0$), the function $$u_k(x,t)=t\sin\left(\frac{\pi k}{a}x\right)$$ does the trick. We could also replace $t$ in the above formula with $\sin(rt)$ for any real number $r$. If all you have to do is find a function satisfying certain boundary conditions, there are usually many options to choose from. Now, if there's a PDE to satisfy, as well as boundary conditions, then that will narrow our options down substantially.

Comment: I was dealing with a PDE for the non-homogeneous wave (string) equation which I believe was $u_{t}-u_{xx}=e^{t}$ and the first step in dealing with this type of problem was to find a function, $v(x,t)$ that satisfied the boundary conditions and the initial condition which were given to me. God I feel like an idiot not being able to to determine the function so I did all the other steps without it but not having it is probably gonna hurt me. I wish you guys were there helpin me today!

Answer (score 2):

$u(x, t) = \cos(x\pi/2)\sin(t) + \sin(x \pi/2) \cos(t)
=\sin(t + x \pi/2)
$

When $x = 0$ you get $\sin(t)$, 
when $x = 1$ you get $\cos(t)$.